# Probability of candy being red

Tags: probability

Me and a friend of mine were eating some leftover candy lying on a desk in the
office the other day. Up until now all of the candy pieces turned out to be
green when unwrapped, and I asked the following question:

There are $n$ pieces of wrapped candy on the table and we unwrap $k$ pieces.
Assume that there are $r$ red pieces of candy, and any piece is either green or red. What's the probability that at least one of the $k$ pieces are red?

We came up with a horrible sum of products, but couldn't figure out how to write this as a closed form. Is there a cute and short formula capturing this?

Comment: Easier to work from the complement.  The probability that none of the chosen candies are red is $\binom {n-r}k\big /\binom nk$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As lulu noted in a comment, the probability of the complementary event that none of the chosen candies is red is

$$
\frac{\binom{n-r}k}{\binom nk}\;,
$$

so the desired probability is

$$
1-\frac{\binom{n-r}k}{\binom nk}\;.
$$